# How to check if user needs to re-authenticate using Firebase Authentication

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase to log in users into my app, but when I am adding the capability to manage their account like changing their email, password and so on. The documentation says that if the user have not recently signed in they need to re-authenticate, but my question is: How can I check if the user have signed in recently or not? According to the docs the error will return `FIRAuthErrorCodeCredentialTooOld`, but how can I check this?

[image: From the Firebase docs:]

Comment: This would be a nice addition to the API which allows an easy UX and easy implementation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 3**
I had to do this yesterday when trying to delete a user. One thing to note is `FIRAuthErrorCodeCredentialTooOld` is now `FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeRequiresRecentLogin`

What I did was trigger a `UIView` to ask for log in details if that error is thrown. Since I was using email and password, that's what I collected from the user in my example.

```
private func deleteUser() {
  //get the current user
  guard let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser else { return }

  currentUser.delete { (error) in
    if error == nil {
      //currentUser is deleted
    } else {
      //this gets the error code
      guard let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) else { return }
      if errorCode == FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeRequiresRecentLogin {
        //create UIView to get user login information
        let loginView = [yourLoginUIViewController]
        self.present(loginView, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
    }
}
```

Once I had the login information I ran this function to reauthenticate the user. In my case I ran it the `loginView` in the above code if the login in was successful:

```
func reauthenticateUserWith(email: String, password: String) {
  FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
    if error == nil {
      //display UIView to delete user again
      let deleteUserView = deleteUserView()
      present(deleteUserView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
      //handle error
      print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
}
```

The `deleteUserView` in my case calls `deleteUser()` on a button tap from the user. You can also use `UIAlertController` in place of the custom `UIView`s, but that's up to you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Update for current **Swift 5**

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

user?.delete { error in
    if let error = error {
        let authErr = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
        if authErr == .requiresRecentLogin {
            // reauthenticate
        }

        // other error
    } else {
        // delete success
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just needed to change `.code` to `._code` to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documents, there is currently no way to check `FIRAuthErrorCodeCredentialTooOld` other than going through the deleting of the account or the other sensitive cases mentioned.

If you are like me and ended up here because you are trying to figure out how to handle removing someone from Auth and removing other user data in Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database, and/or Cloud Storage, then there is a better solution.

Check out the [Delete User Data Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-delete-user-data) from Firebase to handle this. In short, when a user profile is deleted from Auth, you can use this also to delete data associated with the `uid` from those other Firebase data storage tools.